# What does 'via Vote' mean in the timeline of a deleted post?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, code-of-conduct, timeline

On a certain SE site, following my report of a CoC violation, an SE employee appears to have deleted the post. The timeline shows a comment, 'via Vote'. What does this mean?

> [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you gain access to [moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), you gain the ability to vote to delete questions. This ability is extended to answers when you gain access to [trusted user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) privileges.

When you press the delete button on a post you are eligible to delete (moderators can do this at any time) you are effectively "voting" to delete that post. Moderators' actions are binding, which lets them perform any moderation action that relates to voting (for example, closure -- and in this case, deletion) single-handedly.

Take this screenshot example, where two trusted users and a moderator voted to delete an answer:

[image: Screenshot of timeline when a post was deleted by 3 users "via vote"]

As you can see, the comment is still "via vote." The same is true when a moderator *isn't* involved. See this screenshot of the timeline of a question I voted to delete:

[image: Deletion without a moderator, timeline]

Even when you self-delete your own post, it's still performed by vote. Here, I've deleted my own answer:

[image: Self-deletion - timeline view]

During Spam- or Rude-Flag deletion, the Community user is invoked and votes to delete the post. The Community user still has moderator permissions, so it occurs immediately. Here's a screenshot of the Community user deleting a post when it reached the required number of red flags:

[image: Community user deleting and locking a post]

The "via Vote" comment is not present when a post is deleted through six "Recommend Deletion" choices during a Low Quality Post review, though. Here's a screenshot of how that looks:

[image: Recommend Deletion "deleted from review" outcome]

No comment is provided, just the event name: "Post deleted from review."

Trusted users have the "Recommend Deletion" button replaced with "Delete" during a LQP review, but their vote to delete doubles as a "Recommend Deletion" choice during the review. If the post reaches the required trusted-user delete votes, it is deleted "via Vote." If it reaches 6 "recommend deletion" choices, it is "deleted from review."

So, to answer your question more explicitly...

With the exception of LQP review, deleting a post is performed via vote. Moderators' votes to delete are binding, but they are still considered "votes."

Comment: When is it not via vote? Roomba or flag (spam/rude) deletion?

Comment: @muru I went ahead and updated my answer for that case. It actually still is via Vote when Spam/Rude flag deletion occurs, it's just the Community user "votes" to delete. As a moderator, the Community user's delete vote occurs immediately. The exception to these deletions is when it is deleted from LQP review with 6 "recommend deletion" votes.

Answer (score 2):

You will also see that message when you delete one of your own posts, because you "Voted to delete" it.  Moderators have the ability to delete posts instantly, but they are still "Voting to delete" the post, which is why it shows up as "Via Vote".